# How to use params to react router dom link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I got a problem when try to passing id to react router dom link

```
  <Link to="properties/${property.id}/edit">Edit</Link>
```

im sure the "property.id" is defined, but instead of going to the id of the pages, the link show like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/properties/$%7Bproperty.id%7D/edit
```

can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Typo. You are passing a string literal instead of interpolating a string template. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string to the `to` param. You should be passing a template string like this:-

```
<Link to={`/properties/${property.id}/edit/`}>Edit</Link>
```

Comment: I see, it works now, thanks for your answer Yash